# Export Gridview connected to MYSQL data to excel

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I have a simple form created in Visual Studio (VB) which has a data gridview connected to a table in MySQL (hosted in a remote server).

I have the below code to export the grid view to Excel but it takes a really long time to export (around 15 minutes).

The table in MySQL is really small (1000 rows and 60 columns).

Is there a better way to export the complete MySQL table to excel?

PLEASE HELP

CODE:

```
 Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
        Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer


        xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")
        For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            For j = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
                For k As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count
                    On Error Resume Next
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, k) = DataGridView1.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString()
                Next
            Next
        Next
        xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\vbexcel.xlsx")
        xlWorkBook.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there two ways to do this :

1. using rdlc reports.
2. using  gridview exporting.

first way  you need to created rdlc report, then retrieving data into datatable, then call this code:

```
Dim MyDataSource As ReportDataSource = New ReportDataSource("ReportDataSet", MyDataTable)
        reportviewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("MyrdlcReportPath")
        rvSmartCardsIssues.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = True
        rvSmartCardsIssues.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
        rvSmartCardsIssues.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(MyDataSource )
        rvSmartCardsIssues.LocalReport.Refresh()

        Dim warnings As Warning() = Nothing
        Dim streamids As String() = Nothing
        Dim mimeType As String = Nothing
        Dim encoding As String = Nothing
        Dim extension As String = Nothing
        Dim bytes As Byte()
        bytes = rvSmartCardsIssues.LocalReport.Render("Excel", Nothing, mimeType, encoding, extension, streamids, warnings)
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = True
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = mimeType
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ExportedFileName.xls")
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
```

second way that based on this function :

```
Public Shared Sub ExportGridViewToExcelGridView(ByVal Filename As String, ByRef gvr As GridView, ByRef currentPage As Page)

    Dim HtmlForm As System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm = New System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm()
    currentPage.Controls.Add(HtmlForm)
    HtmlForm.Controls.Add(gvr)

    currentPage.Response.Clear()
    currentPage.Response.Buffer = True
    currentPage.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & Filename)
    currentPage.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    currentPage.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    currentPage.Response.Charset = ""
    currentPage.EnableViewState = False
    Using strwriter As New StringWriter
        Dim htmlwrt As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(strwriter)
        HtmlForm.RenderControl(htmlwrt)
        htmlwrt.Flush()
        currentPage.Response.Write(strwriter.ToString)
        currentPage.Response.End()
    End Using
End Sub
```

make sure that when you use second way to set the gridview paging property to false.